# Automate Helm's tiller installation with Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, helm

I need to be able to generate disposable kubernetes environments using `terraform`.  These environments should use `helm` for application deployment and ideally have `tiller` installed during the `terraform` resource provision.

What is the best way of automating this?  Should I "copy" the deployment generated by `helm init` and translate it to `terraform` lingo?  Is there any other solution more elegant than this?

I tried to explicitly declare the `terraform`'s `helm` provider block, but without any real chart deployment it does not bother into installing the `tiller` service.

Comment: helm provider should install tiler by default, but in order to use helm repository data source, there's a need to run `helm init` which installs tiller :( I'm not sure how to force provider to install tiller before you do helm init

Comment: You can actually perform a `helm init` without installing `tiller` by adding the flag `--client-only`.

Comment: I prefer using something like "helm template | kubectl apply -f -" until tiller becomes tillerless in the next version.

Answer (score 1):

How I see there is two options (from my exp):

1. Use configuration for provider. 
   https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/helm/index.html, there is option to install tiller.
2. Use prefabricated modules, for example:
   https://github.com/sagikazarmark/terraform-tiller
   https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Vidimensional/tiller/kubernetes/0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I think this is achieveable with `terraform`s `null_resource` (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/null/resource.html) with `local-exec`.

Example (untested):

```
resource "null_resource" "helm_init_command" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "helm --kubeconfig=<...> init"

}
```